# triggering an anchor within a list item by clicking on the list element

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to trigger a click on an anchor by clicking a list element that is the parent of the anchor.

```
<% conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <% user_status = current_user.id == conversation.sender.id ? conversation.recipient : conversation.sender %>
  <li id="conversation-item_<%= conversation.try(:id) %>">
    <%= gravatar_for(user_status, size: 50) %>
    <%= link_to user_status.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation),
        remote: true,
        class: "conversation-names #{'current-link' if conversation == conversations.first}" %>
    <span class="delete-message"><%= link_to conversation, method: :delete, remote: true do %><i class="fa fa-times"></i><% end %></span>
    <p><%= truncate(conversation.messages.first.try(:body)) %></p>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I want to click the list element and have the link_to anchor clicked as well.

I've tried this:

```
$("#conversation-item").click(function(){
  $("#coversation-names")[0].click()
});
```

html render:

```
<div class="inbox-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns">
      <div class="conversations">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>Chats</h4>
    </li>
      <li id="conversation-item_108" class="current-link">
        <img alt="viewer@example.com" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/426caa1f3e35c0b18f73110d2b2c6f74?d=retro&amp;s=50">
        <a class="conversation-names" data-remote="true" href="/conversations/108/messages">viewer@example.com</a>
        <span class="delete-message"><a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/conversations/108"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
        <p>helllo</p>
      </li>
      <li id="conversation-item_107" class="">
        <img alt="admin@example.com" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?d=retro&amp;s=50">
        <a class="conversation-names " data-remote="true" href="/conversations/107/messages">admin@example.com</a>
        <span class="delete-message"><a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/conversations/107"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
        <p>ffjoafdks</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but nothing is happening.

Comment: can you share the rendered HTML output in browser

Comment: @PranavCBalan edited with html output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the both `id` is followed by something so use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) instead and `coversation-names` is a class so update it to a class selector. Although trigger the event only when clicked element is not the `a`  tag.

```
$('[id^="conversation-item"]').click(function(e){
  // check the clicked element is `a` tag
  if($(e.target).is(':not(.coversation-names)'))
    $('.coversation-names', this).click()
});
```

---

Or prevent the event bubbling using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method.

```
$('[id^="conversation-item"]').click(function(e){
   $('.coversation-names', this).click()
}).on('click','.coversation-names',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when I click the list element.  I think the issue may be due to the fact that I'm iterating through the conversations array and dynamically generating links.

Comment: @NormanChan : oops I just fixed that..... it's because event bubbling......